# Window rendering errors in Windows 11 light mode

Tags: windows-11, dark-mode

I updated from Windows 10 to Windows 11. I use dark mode for Windows, but light mode for apps. I noticed, that sometimes Windows itself, and some apps have rendering errors on their windows. Examples:

- Windows taskbar notification area (lower right corner of the screen): The background of the entire taskbar is dark, as expected, but the font color of the clock and the icons is black, which makes it barely visible (should be white).
- File Explorer app's ribbon: The background of the entire app is light, as expected, but the font color of the ribbon's buttons and icons is white, which makes it barely visible (should be black).
- Firefox's tab bar: The background of the entire app is light, as expected, but the shadow of the active tab is *sometimes* dark, which looks bad (should be light).

The above examples makes me believe, that some colors come incorrectly from light mode instead of dark mode, and vice versa. But here are two further examples from Firefox's tab bar, also experienced only *sometimes*, which cannot be explained this way:

| Bad | Expected |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| [image] | [image] |

The rendering errors on Firefox's tab bar cure, if the mouse is hovered over the erroneous tab.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in Windows, but here is a workaround.

- I changed the mode to dark entirely, i.e. Windows and apps were both dark.
- I used the OS this way for a week, to check whether the bugs appear. They did not.
- I changed the mode back to Custom (Windows to dark, apps to light), and the problem did not reappear.